# swap - how is it allocated and historically tracked

Tags: linux

newbie question here...

looks like my system isn't using swap...

```
root@testvm:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            985         667          72           3         245         176
Swap:             0           0           0
```

a few questions

1. do i have to enable swap?  I realize it's not a good thing and you want to avoid it, but i dont know if it's something you have to turn on or if the OS creates it as needed?  the fact that my server just shows "0" for everything kind of confuses me.
2. is there a way to see if swap was ever used? i believe the "free -m" command shows current usage.  but say for instance somethnig happens overnight that causes swap usage but the situation goes away and the swap is cleared out.  is there a way that i could see it was used?  (time/amount/etc would be great but i'll settle for anything at this point).

thanks!

Comment: Swap space is a physical disk partition, typically configured when the operating system is installed. It is used automatically by the OS to cache data from your physical memory (RAM) when you run out of memory space. It is considered bad to use it too much because disk i/o is very slow compared to real memory. That said, many programs require that you have a certain amount of it available, even if they don't need it right away; it is a safeguard against total failure (slow is better than dead) for some programs. See here: https://opensource.com/article/18/9/swap-space-linux-systems

Comment: Swap can also be configured on files (though physical partitions or logical volumes are the norm). To see if you have anything configured and enabled, use `swapon -s`.